# while sending data from one DB to other DB throught WAS 8.0 i geting Errorcode--4461,sqlstate=42815 (Data Conversion error)

Tags: websphere

while sending data from one DB to other DB throught WAServer 8.0 diffrent data sources i getting data convertion error while secound record insertion fisrt record saving fine secound record also have the sam erecord data  Errocode=-4461,sqlstate=42815  but once restart the WAS server the same application(secound recored inserting fine) can any one help on this one

Thank you in Advance...

Comment: Please include the exact error message from the logs.  Retagging to 'websphere' since I think that's what you meant, but the description needs to be clearer.

Comment: [jcc][1091][10404][3.57.82] Invalid data conversion: Parameter instance  is invalid for the requested conversion. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815

Comment: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.Exception: [jcc][1091][10404][3.57.82] Invalid data conversion: Parameter instance  is invalid for the requested conversion. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815

Comment: Is this error being printed in the WebSphere logs?  If yes, please update your answer to have the full exception stack trace.  If no, where are these errors coming from?

Comment: [6/20/13 9:59:43:990 IST]     FFDC Exception:com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io SourceId:com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.setString ProbeId:1010 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJccPreparedStatement@218a790
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io: [jcc][1091][10404][3.57.82] Invalid data conversion: Parameter instance  is invalid for the requested conversion. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:676)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:60)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:103)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fc.a(fc.java:662)

Comment: That's a little more information, but you should update your question description with the full stack trace.